# Google analytics click event tracking firing twice

Tags: google-analytics, click

I have an Isotope #container div with many .item divs, which can be maximised and minimised by a click in their nested .header div. They also minimise automatically when a viewer directly clicks another content div without minimising (clicking the header) the currently maximised one.

Therefore, the Google analytics event tracking is sometimes fired twice: when the viewer does not directly click in the .header div of another .item div - but decides to minimise the currently maximised one by clicking it first, before clicking another.

How should I modify the logic so ever only one click event is registered in my analytics?

```
$('.header').click(function () { // instead of registering the entire .item div (default use), only its .header div (child div) receives clicks

    var $previousSelected = $('.selected'); // necessary for maximising and minimising

    if ($(this).parent().hasClass('selected')) { // use $(this).parent() - not $(this) - because the .header div is a child of the .item div

        $(this).parent().removeClass('selected');
        $(this).parent().children('.maximised').hide();
        $(this).parent().children('.minimised').show();

        $items.find('.minimised').removeClass('overlay'); // returns all .minimised divs to previous state after the .item is closed again

    } else {

        $previousSelected.removeClass('selected');
        $previousSelected.children('.minimised').show();
        $previousSelected.children('.maximised').hide();

        $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
        $(this).parent().children('.minimised').hide();
        $(this).parent().children('.maximised').show();

        $items.not('.selected').find('.minimised').addClass('overlay'); // adds .overlay on each .item which is not currently .selected

    }

    $container.isotope('reLayout');

    <!-- ga project interest tracking -->

    var clicked = $(this).parent().data('item');
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Items viewed', 'Clicked', clicked, null, true]);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if I understand correctly, you only want to fire the GA tracking when something is maximized:

```
$(this).parent().children('.maximised').show(function(){
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Items viewed', 'Clicked', clicked, null, true]);
});
```

You could also try at the bottom of your `.click` function:

```
if( $(this).parent().children('.maximised').is(':visible') ){
   _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Items viewed', 'Clicked', clicked, null, true]); 
}
```

Comment: Exactly, only clicks that maximise shall trigger an event, not clicks that minimise, as it happens now.

Comment: OK, updated my answer to use the `.show` callback function to fire the GA event.

Comment: Almost there. I can see in Chrome's devtools, that if I shift it to the .show callback, the __utm.gif is indeed sent with the correct data. However, this breaks Isotope's layout function - the layout engine assumes the size of the .item is only the .header exluding the maximised content below. Somehow, the callback breaks something...

Comment: What does it say in Chrome's console? Are you seeing any specific js errors?

Comment: Well, console remains empty; no errors, warnings, etc. I noticed however, that after this quirk occurs - when the browser window is resized - the layout takes the size of the maximised .item into account. So that means using the callback somehow interferes with Isotope's layout engine until the window is resized. Never had this before, did various Isotope sites.

Comment: @Systembolaget I added the `.is(':visible')` option to my answer. Give that a try.

Comment: Thank you very much for your persistence - your solution provides the correct behaviour; only one __utm.gif is sent per .item viewed, no matter which path the viewer follows through the site.

Comment: @Systembolaget You're welcome +1 for sticking with me as well.